# How to compare power of two differences?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, spss, statistical-power

We choose two samples:

- One with inhabitants of **City A**
- One with inhabitants of **City B**

The height and weight of samples were measured. The differences of height and weight of samples of two cities were statistically significant (P-value < .05).

How can I calculate which of these differences (height or weight) is more prominant between the inhabitants of the two cities?

Can someone give me an example using `SPSS`?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the effect size for height and weight and sort the factors by them. The effect size will reveal practical significance of the differences and give you better understanding of the data. Take a look at Cohen's $d$. Although I don't think that it is available in SPSS, it has a rather simple formula and you can compute its value with a calculator or by hand. Once you have the values of $d$ for weight and height, you will be able to determine if the differences represent small, medium or large effects and which difference has larger effect.